# How to style SVG <g> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have some SVG elements grouped together in a `<g>` element. I just want to style that `<g>` element to show grouping of elements. Like I want to give some background-color and a border to it. How it would be achieved?

I tried `fill` and `stroke` attribute to `<g>` element, but it doesn't work. How it would be possible?

[Sample Here](http://jsfiddle.net/VBmbP/1/)

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="blue" stroke="2">
            <rect id="svg_6" height="112" width="84" y="105" x="136" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#00ff00"/>
        <ellipse fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" cx="271" cy="156" id="svg_7" rx="64" ry="56"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: there are several js libraries for this. Try http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: can raphaeljs group svg elements?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You actually cannot draw [Container Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#TermContainerElement)

But you can use a "foreignObject" with a "SVG" inside it to simulate what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/csoyefb9/

```html
   <svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <foreignObject id="G" width="300" height="200">
            <svg id="S">
              <rect fill="blue" stroke-width="2" height="112" width="84" y="55" x="55" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000"/>
              <ellipse fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" cx="155" cy="65" id="svg_7" rx="64" ry="56"/>     
            </svg>
            <style>
                  #S {
                    background: #fcf; border: 1px dashed black;
                  }
                  #S:hover {
                    background: #cac; border: 1px solid black;
                  }
            </style>
     </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but a foreignObject is not intended for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject In that sense it is no more appropriate than a rect object.

Comment: But you can't nest elements inside a rect, can you?

Comment: And foreignObject browser support is supper limited yet at this date.

Comment: Support has increased a lot after all this time https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_svgforeignobjectelement

Comment: Just tested the fiddle in FF and setting background still doesn't work. Works in Safari and Chromium browsers though.

Comment: It works in all browsers if you add the style to the svg element. I've updated the answer's code. Thx

Answer (score 70):

You cannot add style to an SVG `<g>` element. Its only purpose is to group children. That means, too, that style attributes you give to it are given down to its children, so a `fill="green"` on the `<g>` means an automatic `fill="green"` on its child `<rect>` (as long as it has no own `fill` specification).

Your only option is to add a new `<rect>` to the SVG and place it accordingly to match the `<g>` children's dimensions.

Comment: That's mostly true, but there are some properties such as e.g `opacity` that apply to the <g> element itself.

Comment: Will children of a `<g>` element inherit its `class` attributes? (tests suggest they do, meaning you can apply a css-sensitive class to a `<g>` element and have all the children inherit that class' styling attributes)

Answer (score 35):

I know its long after this question was asked and answered - and I am sure that the accepted solution is right, but the purist in me would rather not add an extra element to the SVG when I can achieve the same or similar with straight CSS.

Whilst it is true that you cannot style the `g` container element in most ways - you can definitely add an outline to it and style that - even changing it on hover of the `g` - as shown in the snippet.

It not as good in one regard as the other way - you can put the outline box around the grouped elements - but not a background behind it. Sot its not perfect and won't solve the issue for everyone - but I would rather have the outline done with css than have to add extra elements to the code just to provide styling hooks.

And this method definitely allows you to show grouping of related objects in your SVG's.

Just a thought.

```css
g {
    outline: solid 3px blue;
    outline-offset: 5px;
  }

g:hover {
 outline-color: red
}
```

```html
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <rect fill="blue" stroke-width="2" height="112" width="84" y="55" x="55" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke="#000000"/>
    <ellipse fill="#FF0000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-linecap="null" cx="155" cy="65" id="svg_7" rx="64" ry="56"/>     
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for my use-case (just needed a visual clue of what was the content of a group)

Comment: This appears to be browser-dependent; it does work on Google Chrome, but not on Safari.

Answer (score 10):

The style that you give the "g" element will apply the child elements, not the "g" element itself.

Add a rectangle element and position around the group you wish to style.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

EDIT: updated wording and added fiddle in comments.

Comment: The `<rect>` is not allowed to have shapes or `<g>` as chidlren (not even in [SVG2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/shapes.html#RectElement)). It will therefore not simply span to meet its children's dimensions.

Comment: @Boldewyn I meant graphically, not literally, but I will rephrase to make that clear. As seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/VBmbP/2/