# My app works in Chrome but not iPhone; what is my cross-browser compatibility issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, cross-browser

I am working on a billiards scorekeeping app implemented in HTML/CSS/javascript at this repo:
https://github.com/Zenilogix-Carl/Site

I have been developing using Windows and Chrome, getting expected outputs or at least able to diagnose issues in that environment. I've seen it run on some friends' iPhones and I get very different (and flawed) results. I am hoping to find someone who can help me identify and correct the issues affecting iPhone.

The three files relevant to my issue are:

- NineBall.html
- Billiards.js
- styles.css

I've attached screenshots below. Notice that in Chrome, all balls are rendered with a drop-shadow; this is defined in the BilliardBall class and extended into BilliardBallWithState (both in Billiards.js) and, depending on current state, may be turned on or off by function updateBallState in NineBall.html. Initial state should show the drop-shadow for all balls, which it does in Chrome, but fails to on iPhone.

```
class BilliardBall {
    constructor(number, size, allowForShadow) {
        var colors = ["yellow", "blue", "red", "purple", "orange", "green", "brown", "var(--ballBlack)"];
        var color = Number.isInteger(number) ? colors[(number - 1) % 8] : colors[0];
        var isStripe = Number.isInteger(number) ? (((number - 1) / 8) >= 1) : false;

        this.number = number;

        var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
        svg.setAttribute("viewBox", allowForShadow ? "0 0 120 120" : "0 0 105 100");
        svg.setAttribute("width", size);
        svg.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");
        var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
        this.ballGraphic = g;
        var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");

        if (isStripe) {
            circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("r", 48);
            circle.setAttribute("style", "fill: white;");
            g.appendChild(circle);

            var path = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
            path.setAttribute("d", "M 16 16 L 84 16 A 50 50 0 0 1 84 84 L 16 84  A 50 50 0 0 1 16 16 ");
            path.setAttribute("style", "fill: " + color + "; stroke-width: 1; stroke: grey;");
            g.appendChild(path);

            circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
            circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("r", 48);
            circle.setAttribute("style", "fill: transparent; stroke-width: 1; stroke: var(--ballOutline);");
            g.appendChild(circle);

        } else {
            circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
            circle.setAttribute("r", 48);
            circle.setAttribute("style", `fill: ${color}; stroke-width: 1; stroke: var(--ballOutline);`);
            g.appendChild(circle);
        }

        circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
        circle.setAttribute("cx", 50);
        circle.setAttribute("cy", 50);
        circle.setAttribute("r", 27);
        circle.setAttribute("style", "fill: white; stroke-width: 1; stroke: grey;");
        g.appendChild(circle);
        var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        text.setAttribute("x", 50);
        text.setAttribute("y", 53);
        text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "middle");
        text.setAttribute("dominant-baseline", "middle");
        text.setAttribute("font-weight", "bold");
        text.setAttribute("font-size", number > 9 ? "32px" : "40px");
        text.innerHTML = number;
        g.appendChild(text);
        svg.appendChild(g);

        this.element = svg;
    }
}

class BilliardBallWithState extends BilliardBall {

    constructor(number, size, clickFn, foulText) {
        super(number, size, true);

        const svg = this.element;
        svg.onclick = function () { clickFn(number)};
        let text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        text.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
        text.classList.add("dropShadow");
        text.setAttribute("x", 50);
        text.setAttribute("y", 50);
        text.setAttribute("text-anchor", "middle");
        text.setAttribute("dominant-baseline", "middle");
        text.setAttribute("font-size", "30px");
        text.setAttribute("fill", "red");
        text.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
        text.setAttribute("stroke", "white");
        text.innerHTML = foulText;
        svg.appendChild(text);
        this.foulText = text;
        text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "text");
        text.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden;");
        text.classList.add("dropShadow");
        text.setAttribute("x", 40);
        text.setAttribute("y", 90);
        text.setAttribute("font-size", "80px");
        text.setAttribute("fill", "green");
        text.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
        text.setAttribute("stroke", "white");
        text.innerHTML = "&#x2714;";
        svg.appendChild(text);
        this.checkMark = text;

        this.showNormal();
    }

    dimElement(elem, dim) {
        if (dim) {
            elem.classList.remove("dropShadow");
            elem.classList.add("dimmed");
        } else {
            elem.classList.add("dropShadow");
            elem.classList.remove("dimmed");
        }
    }

    showElement(elem, show) {
        elem.style.visibility = show ? "visible" : "hidden";
    }

    showNormal() {
        this.dimElement(this.ballGraphic, false);
        this.showElement(this.foulText, false);
        this.showElement(this.checkMark, false);
    }

    showPocketed(checked) {
        this.dimElement(this.ballGraphic, true);
        this.showElement(this.foulText, false);
        this.showElement(this.checkMark, checked);
    }

    showFoul() {
        this.dimElement(this.ballGraphic, true);
        this.showElement(this.foulText, true);
        this.showElement(this.checkMark, false);
    }
}

    function updateBallState(number) {
        const currentBallState = match.ballStates[number - 1];
        const ball = balls[number];

        switch (currentBallState) {
            case "normal":
                ball.showNormal();
                break;

            case "dead":
                ball.showFoul();
                break;

            default:
                ball.showPocketed(currentBallState === "won");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Also, although not reflecting in the screen caps, it seems that cookies are not working correctly on iPhone, so I am wondering if I am handling them correctly - see onLoad function in NineBall.html and Preferences class in Billiards.js.

I need to understand what I am doing that is not functional/uniformly supported across browsers and what I need to do for my app to run correctly in both Android (Chrome) and iPhone (presumably Safari) browsers.

**Chrome screen-cap (expected appearance):**

[image: Expected appearance (Chrome)]

---

**iPhone screen-cap (shows anomaly as described above):**

[image: Actual appearance (iPhone)]

**EDIT**

Added one more screenshot to illustrate the different pool ball display states I am aiming for. This is on Chrome, so shows what I expect. Note how dimmed state is optionally combined with checkmark or "DEAD" text, both of which are *not* dimmed and have the drop-shadow to help them stand out. I mention this because of its relevance to the way individual component elements can or cannot be grouped for styling.

[image: Pool balls in different display states]

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2:**

After reading the comments on this answer and learning more about your goals for the project, I believe I have found an acceptable solution to your problem.

It seems like you are grouping the idea of effects and overlaid elements together, but I believe they are separate issues. The solution I proposed below would take care of the effects problem. By applying custom classes to the `svg` element itself, you should be able to apply custom effects in a browser safe way.

However, for the overlaid elements, I think the best approach is actually a separate element that is overlaying the pool ball. From what I can see, a lot of your overlaid elements are reused. I would propose that the reused elements be saved as site resources, and applied to either a separate HTML element, or a `background-image` as a pseudo-element. The code below has not been tested, but is intended to give a more clear picture of my proposition:

```css
/* General styling. `position: relative;` needed on a parent to correctly set the context for an absolutely positioned child */
.ball {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Applies to all SVG elements under .ball container */
.ball svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: green;
}

/* Applies drop shadow to the applicable SVG */
svg.dropShadow {
  box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px black;
}

/* Properly dims applicable SVGs */
svg.dimmed {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

/* "Check" in this case is a small red circle that is overlaid on the dimmed SVG */
svg.check {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="balls">
    <!-- Default ball behavior -->
    <div class="ball">
        <svg class="dropShadow">
        </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- Dimmed and checked ball behavior -->
    <div class="ball">
        <!-- The `check` class would absolutely position this element over and in front of the ball itself -->
        <svg class="check">
        </svg>
        <svg class="dimmed">
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update:**

After a fair amount of digging, I am satisfied with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18697658/1469683) in another Stack Overflow post.

It seems that the `g` element is intended only to be a container, and is not designed to have style applied to it. While most browsers work as expected, applying styling to the `g` element directly does not appear to be officially supported functionality. As my initial answer suggests, it seems like the best course of action is to move your styling classes to the parent SVG element.

---

I don't yet have the *why* part of your issue, but it appears that when run on iOS, all of the elements that still have a drop shadow have the `dropShadow` class set on the `svg` element itself, whereas all the elements with missing drop shadows, the class is being added to the direct child `g` element.

Initially, I thought that iOS WebKit had nonstandard behavior for clipping SVG elements, but then I realized that your `dimmed` class also does not function on the iPhone.

Tweaking your JavaScript to apply the classes to the `svg` element itself, rather than the `g` element, should be a negligible change to your code that should get you on your way.

I'm going to keep looking into this... I would like to know *why* iOS behaves this way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, applying to the parent svg won't work for my current structure because I have a checkmark which needs to display "normally" under a case where the ball is dimmed, but the whole svg also needs to position/scale as one entity. I think my answer is nested svg instead of g.

Comment: @Zenilogix: This shouldn't be problem – just add/toggle multiple classes. Nested svgs wont't solve the webkit related issue: The outmost `<svg>` element is still treated as a HTML element (accepting css styles like filters – that's why you can e.g. apply padding to the outmost svg that otherwise doesn't have any effect on svg child elements), although it "introduces" the SVG DOM. Any nested `<svg>` is within the SVG DOM won't accept CSS filters (at least in webkit). Please correct me/share your insights, if you found a running workaround using nested svg tags.

Comment: @herrstrietzel My end goal is to create a composite visual element (the pool ball) on which I can toggle a few effects included the drop shadow, dimming, and overlaid text elements (checkmark, etc.). The composite pool ball element needs to both scale and flow in a <DIV> container. My critical revelation was about styling of svg elements. Given that, I suppose the focus of my problem is about how to construct the pool ball element such that it satisfies the requirement for toggled effects, scaling, and flow.

Comment: @Zenilogix It's very frustrating that in 2023 we still have to worry about browser compatibility issues. I've updated my answer with what I believe to be the best solution to you problem, thanks to the additional context given in the comments.

Comment: @ClintWarner I was already experimenting with a few different nestings, including using DIVs as you suggested, but I was getting unexpected layout behaviors e.g. each DIV starts on a new line or everything (all balls and their overlays) all overlay onto a single spot instead of desired overlay for each ball with each ball laying out across the page. I also tried nesting in a SPAN which seemed to work better, but I got weird wrapping behaviors (one element inside the SPAN would wrap before the other).

Comment: It sounds like you were not absolutely positioning the `div` element in order for it to overlay the pool ball. I've updated my answer to include a more comprehensive code snippet to give an idea of what the CSS could look like to accomplish what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can apply css styles to SVG `<g>` elements that will can inherited – but apparently **webkit does not accept css filters applied to SVG child elements**.

I could reproduce this rendering issue in Epiphany/Web and Midori (running in a virtual Linux Mint environment).

#### Workaround: CSS drop shadow for parent `<svg>` SVG filter for child elements

As suggested by [Clint Warner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324778/my-app-works-in-chrome-but-not-iphone-what-is-my-cross-browser-compatibility-is/76343248#76343248) you can apply the CSS drop shadow to the outer `<svg>` elements.

Inner child elements can use a native SVG filter.

You could add an invisible svg containing a native svg filter like this:

```
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <filter y="-50%" height="250%" id='dropshadowSvg' color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="5" flood-opacity="1" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

and apply it via css rule/inline style

```
.dropShadowSVG {
    filter: url(#dropshadowSvg);
}
```

```css
:root{
      --background: lightblue;
    --popupBackground: white;
    --foreground: black;
    --dropShadowFilter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 5px black);
    --ballOutline: grey;
    --ballBlack: black;
}

svg{
  overflow:visible;
  width:25%;
}


.dropShadowCSS {
    filter: var(--dropShadowFilter);
}

.dropShadowSVG {
    filter: url(#dropshadowSvg);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0">
  <filter y="-50%" height="250%" id='dropshadowSvg' color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="5" flood-opacity="1" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<div id="balls" style="padding: 10px;">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120"  class="dropShadowCSS">
    <g>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" style="fill: yellow; stroke-width: 1; stroke: var(--ballOutline);"></circle>
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="27" style="fill: white; stroke-width: 1; stroke: grey;"></circle><text x="50" y="53" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-weight="bold" font-size="40px">⏳</text>
    </g><text style="visibility: visible;" class="dropShadow" x="50" y="75" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="30px" fill="white" stroke-width="1" stroke="white"></text><text style="visibility: hidden;" class="dropShadow" x="40" y="90" font-size="80px" fill="green" stroke-width="1" stroke="white">✔</text>
  </svg>

  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120"  class="dropShadowCSS">
    <g style="color:purple">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" style="fill: #ccc; stroke-width: 1; stroke: grey ;">
      </circle>
      <text class="dropShadowSVG" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="1">Time-out</text>

    </g>
  </svg>
  
  <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" class="dropShadowCSS">
    <g style="color:purple">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="48" style="fill: #ccc; stroke-width: 1; stroke: grey ;">
      </circle>
      <text class="dropShadowCSS" x="50" y="50" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="1">Time-out</text>

    </g>
  </svg>
  

</div>
```