# How to add custom CSS to gantt chart highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, highcharts-gantt

How can i add border around the date range buttons in the Gantt chart?
Something like below screen shot
[image: Image with border around dates button and with different background color]

It possible to add my custom css to the chart as shown in the screenshot?

[image: background color added in paint]

Answer (score 0):

You can add that kind of border using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer`:

Example:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;

        if (chart.rect) {
          chart.rect = chart.rect.destroy();
        }
        
        chart.rect = chart.renderer.rect(x, y, width, height)
          .attr({
            stroke: color,
          }).add();
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qse2zf0/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

Comment: Actually i wanted to add custome css to that box like border-radius and background color

Comment: I added one more image to the question. I tried to change background color using css but chart just does not honor it

Comment: I'm not sure what element you try to style. When it comes to the `.highcharts-range-selector-group` there are some limitations of styling svg elements (SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697278/how-to-style-svg-g-element), that's why rendering the rectangle is a more customizable option in that case https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5tzpkcge/